# Why would I receive UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL ? CS50 Pset2 Crack

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, cs50

I get this error during runtime not on compilation. I Isolated the line that causes the error which is 44 (Removing it avoids the error). Code snippet and error message is given below.

Based on my research, Error message suggests that I am trying to write into part of the memory that I should not be accessing. For another problem I have done something similar: pass a string from main to a function, edit some chars inside string within the function and return that string to a different variable. I tried assigning returned string to a new variable but error still comes up. What can I do to understand and avoid this error in the future ?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>

string get_nextkey(string currentkey);
int get_nextchar(char current);

string starters[5] = {"A", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA"};

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string hash = argv[1];
        char salt[3];
        salt[0] = hash[0];
        salt[1] = hash[1];
        salt[2] = '\0';
        printf("%lu %s\n",strlen(salt),salt);
        string key = "A";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            printf("testing key: %s\n",key);
            string keyhash = crypt(key, salt);
            if (strcmp(hash,keyhash) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n",key);
                return 0;
            }
            key = get_nextkey(key);
        }     
    }
    printf("Usage: ./crack hash\n");
    return 1;
}

string get_nextkey(string currentkey)
{
    int length = strlen(currentkey);
    int nextchar = get_nextchar(currentkey[length-1]);
    if (nextchar != 0)
    {
        currentkey[length-1] = nextchar;
    }
    return currentkey;
}

int get_nextchar(char current)
{
    int nextchar = current + 1;
    if (nextchar < 123)
    {
        if (nextchar > 90 && nextchar < 97)
        {
            nextchar = 97;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return nextchar;
}
```

```
$ ./crack 50cI2vYkF0YU2
2 50
testing key: A
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==1361==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00000042b316 (pc 0x000000422b46 bp 0x7fff6b45cc20 sp 0x7fff6b45cb60 T1361)
==1361==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
    #0 0x422b45  (/root/sandbox/crack+0x422b45)
    #1 0x422836  (/root/sandbox/crack+0x422836)
    #2 0x7f00a0281b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x402b79  (/root/sandbox/crack+0x402b79)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==1361==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string key = "A";
crypt(key, ...);
```

Is invalid. The `string key` points to a string literal `"A"`. A string literal `"A"` is immutable and can't be modified, while `crypt` expects a valid pointer to a 7 byte buffer (at least).

Do:

```
char key[7];
crypt(key, ....);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can mutate the chars inside that char array.